# "Не вели казнить!"

Tags: старославянский

Если вспомним эту формулировку по отношению к царю - "не вели казнить, вели слово молвить", то обратим внимание, что обращение к царю идет на "ты". При этом, понятно, что обращение к царю самое уважительное.
А существовало ли тогда, в старой речи, обращение на "вы"? И когда оно вообще появилось в русской речи и почему?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тогда ещё не было "вы", в России это обращение появилось со времени введения Петром I Табели о рангах (1722 г.), где предписывалось обращаться так к старшим по званию.

Answer (score 2):

Может быть, вам покажутся  интересными эти статьи (правда, материал в них имеет дискуссионный характер:

http://www.pravdu.net/publ/kak_obrashhatsja_na_vy_ili_na_ty_kak_na_rusi_vykat_stali/1-1-0-36

http://otvet.mail.ru/question/15556248